# Is it useful to compress localStorage?

Tags: html, compression, local-storage

I'll start off with a solid example: I have a function that generates hashes (32-bit integers) and saves them in localStorage. This is to implement a "don't show me again" feature for common notifications: if the hash is in the list, don't show the notification.

After my first attempt at coding this solution, my localStorage entry looked like this:

> 616845040,796177849,848184043,1133088406,1205053317,1478518197,1525440546,1686606993,1753347541,1908577591,2056496592,-864967541,-1185668678,-835401591,-1017499054,-559563441,-1842092814,-1069291933,-1887162563

**19 hashes, 210 bytes of data.**

A little later, I revisited the code. Instead of just dumping the integers as decimal strings, I converted them into actual binary data. In other words, each hash is now a string of four characters in length representing the binary value of the integer. My localStorage entry now looks like this:

> $ÄNð/tµ¹2BëCGÓ§X eµZì`"dhõÕqÂ7z¥Ðￌq¤ﾹT!ºￎ4ÈￃZ2R￞¥½Oﾒ3äò￀Cæcﾏ/=

**19 hashes, 76 bytes of data** (There's some non-printable characters in there)

That's a savings of 63.8%.

Now, I am well aware that localStorage provides, by default, 5MB of storage space. I could easily store tens of thousands of hashes with the first method with no issues at all. But I like being efficient. I certainly wouldn't want a 5MB file on my computer when I could have the same data in 1.8MB (same compression ratio as above). That's why I save all my PNGs as indexed-palette when possible.

Is this a good mentality to have? Or am I just being pedantic? I guess this question could be summarised as: **Should I compress, or just not care due to having more resources than I'll ever need?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pedantic is good when coming to code. Compress when you can, but be sure that when reading your **code**, it's still readable and understandable that hashes are kept in whatever way.

What I mean is, don't sacrifice your code readability and maintainability for efficiency.

Comment: Binary may be a source of errors here because of character encoding issues. Perhaps use base64, base36 or just hex numbers to get some compression, still avoiding unreadable content that is hard to debug...